# Check if the nested list has duplicates

Tags: python, list

I have lists inside of the list and would like to check the duplicates and delete them

the example of the list is:

```
[[(12, 12, {(36023,)}, ('modena',))], 
[(8, 9, {(38008,)}, ('#', 'ferrara')), (9, 9, {(38008,)}, ('ferrara',)), (14, 15, {(38017,)}, ('#', 'ostellato')), (15, 15, {(38017,)}, ('ostellato',))], 
[(15, 15, {(65068,)}, ('minori',))]]
```

what I would like to obtain is:

```
[[(12, 12, {(36023,)}, ('modena',))], 
[(8, 9, {(38008,)}, ('#', 'ferrara')), (14, 15, {(38017,)}, ('#', 'ostellato'))], 
[(15, 15, {(65068,)}, ('minori',))]]
```

Comment: You want to remove duplicates based on what? non of the elements are exactly the same and you still removed them in the expected output

Comment: Duplicates based on 3rd element

Comment: Use set(mylist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    [(12, 12, {(36023,)}, ("modena",))],
    [
        (8, 9, {(38008,)}, ("#", "ferrara")),
        (9, 9, {(38008,)}, ("ferrara",)),
        (14, 15, {(38017,)}, ("#", "ostellato")),
        (15, 15, {(38017,)}, ("ostellato",)),
    ],
    [(15, 15, {(65068,)}, ("minori",))],
]

out = []
for subl in lst:
    seen = set()
    out.append([])
    for tpl in subl:
        _, _, s, *_ = tpl
        s = frozenset(s)
        if s not in seen:
            out[-1].append(tpl)
            seen.add(s)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[[(12, 12, {(36023,)}, ('modena',))], 
 [(8, 9, {(38008,)}, ('#', 'ferrara')), 
  (14, 15, {(38017,)}, ('#', 'ostellato'))], 
 [(15, 15, {(65068,)}, ('minori',))]]
```